# VBA Charting issues

Tags: excel, charts, rows, vba

I combined two codes I found within these posts but now the graphs are not showing the data in the Range("B2:C2"). I am just starting to learn how to write macro's so bear with me. Can someone help?

Thank you in advance

```
Sub test()

Range("A2").Select

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range

 Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set rng = ws.Range("B2:C2").Offset(Row, 0)

 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
 ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(ws.Name & "!" & rng.Address)
 ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
 ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Sheet1'!$B$2:$C$2"
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ws.Range("A2").Offset(Row, 0).Value
 ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
 ws.Select

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop

 Set ws = Nothing
 Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to use a while loop. while (the cell is not blank) do what ever u need to do. I guess that this is VB(u should mention the language) so i am not sure how u handle the cells and their values.

Comment: thank you, i added a do loop but now it wont chart the data.

Comment: edit/update your code

Comment: I did, still wont show data. I'm not sure where my mistake is.

Answer (score 2):

You can establish the last row that has data and use that row number in your For/Next loop. Something like this:

```
Sub test()
 Dim Row As Integer, lastRow As Integer
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range

 Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
 lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - 1
 Debug.Print lastRow

 For Row = 1 To lastRow
 Set rng = ws.Range("B1:C1").Offset(Row, 0)

 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
 ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(ws.Name & "!" & rng.Address)
 ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
 ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Sheet1'!$B$1:$C$1"
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ws.Range("A1").Offset(Row, 0).Value
 ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
 ws.Select

 Next Row

 Set ws = Nothing
 Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way. Avoid using `.Select`, `.ActiveChart` etc...

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ObjChrt As Object
    Dim Chrt As Chart

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find the last row
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Loop through the values
        For i = 2 To lRow
            Set rng = .Range("B" & i & ":C" & i)

            '~~> Work with Chart Objects
            Set ObjChrt = .Shapes.AddChart
            Set Chrt = ObjChrt.Chart

            '~~> Assign relevant values
            With Chrt
                .SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range(rng.Address)
                .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
                .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$" & i & ":$C$" & i
                .SeriesCollection(1).Name = ws.Range("A" & i).Value
                .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
            End With
        Next i
    End With

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks everyone for your help. I will try it over the weekend.